# Query MySQL Intervalo de tempo

Tags: mysql

Olá, precisaria fazer uma consulta em um intervalo de tempo no mysql, esse intervalo gostaria que fosse o INICIO (data atual) FIM ( data atual + 365 dias (1 ano)), tentei com o CURDATE() mas não funcionou.

```
 BETWEEN  CURDATE()  AND CURDATE() + 365
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o "DATE_ADD()" junto com o "CURDATE()".
Essa função recebe 3 parâmetros, que são: A data que será modificada, o intervalo que pode ser positivo ou negativo e por último o tipo de intervalo.

Tipos de intervalos que podem ser utilizados:

```
MICROSECOND
SECOND
MINUTE
HOUR
DAY
WEEK
MONTH
QUARTER
YEAR
SECOND_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
HOUR_MICROSECOND
HOUR_SECOND
HOUR_MINUTE
DAY_MICROSECOND
DAY_SECOND
DAY_MINUTE
DAY_HOUR
YEAR_MONTH
```

```
SELECT * FROM `nome_da_tabela` WHERE `nome_da_coluna` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE data BETWEEN date(now())-20 AND data
```

O select acima retorná **entre** a data atual menos 20 dias e a data atual.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a03df/4/0